# Only keep the First and Last Revision of a post

Tags: custom-post-types, revisions

I've got a custom post type where the posts often undergo several minor revisions.

Saving all the revisions is unnecessary and seems wasteful to keep so many useless DB entries.

But I do need to keep the **Original** (first published version) and the **Latest** (most recently updated version).

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to accomplish this?